# cannot convert type char to string

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm doing data involving arrays in C#, when I use the foreach loop it gave me an message

> cannot convert type char to string

```
int[,] tel = new int[4, 8];
tel[0, 0] = 398;
tel[0, 1] = 3333;
tel[0, 2] = 2883;
tel[0, 3] = 17698;
tel[1, 0] = 1762;
tel[1, 1] = 176925;
tel[1, 2] = 398722;
tel[2, 0] = 38870;
tel[3, 1] = 30439;

foreach (string t in tel.ToString())
{
    Console.WriteLine(tel +" " +"is calling");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is becuase when you `foreach` over a `string` each value will be a `char`, but you are trying to cast them to `string`.

```
 foreach(string t in tel.ToString())
```

But it's unlikely that you want to `foreach` on `tel.ToString()` as the will return the name of the type of `tel` (`System.Int32[,]`).  Instead you probably want to iterate all the values in `tel`

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(tel[i,j] +" is calling");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Or

```
foreach(int t in tel)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t +" is calling");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Note that some of the values will be zero since you do not assign values to all the positions in the `tel` array.

Comment: It may be important to note that tel.ToString() is returning the type name, not any value in the array. The only reason the foreach works is because string is implicitly convertible to a char array which is an IEnumerable. Its complaining about the conversion back through that chain to the string at the front...

Comment: @RonBeyer I did mention that `tel.ToString()` returns the type name.  But to be clear I've included the actual string that is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the values in the array like this:

```
int rowLength = tel.GetLength(0);
int colLength = tel.GetLength(1);

for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(tel[i, j]+" is calling");
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```