# Loop through sub directories in directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, directory, subdirectory

I have a directory 'Folder' with many subdirectories inside this directory. Inside every subdirectory there are many images. I want to loop through subdirectories in the 'Folder' directory, then loop through all images in every directory to export the images out to Excel, with images from each subdirectory in one Excel worksheet.

For e.g. if I have ten subdirectories, I should have one Excel workbook with ten Excel worksheets, then in each Excel worksheet there will be images from each subdirectory.

**This is what I have tried but images only appeared on Worksheet1 instead of all the worksheets:**

```
   public void ExportToExcel()
        {
            //for export
            ExcelPackage objExcelPackage = new ExcelPackage();   //create new workbook

            string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetDirectories(Server.MapPath("~/Folder"));
            int count = 0;
            int count1 = 0;
            int x = 25;
            int finalValue = 0;

            foreach (string subdir in filesindirectory)
            {                      
                count++;
                ExcelWorksheet ws = objExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet" + count); //create new worksheet

            foreach (string img in Directory.GetFiles(subdir))
            {
                count1++;
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image TEST_IMAGE = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                System.Drawing.Image myImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(img);
                var pic = ws.Drawings.AddPicture(count1.ToString(), myImage);
                // Row, RowoffsetPixel, Column, ColumnOffSetPixel
                if (count1 > 1)
                {
                    pic.SetPosition(finalValue, 0, 2, 0);
                    finalValue += (x + 1); // Add 1 to have 1 row of empty row
                }
                else
                {
                    pic.SetPosition(count1, 0, 2, 0);
                    finalValue = (count1 + x) + 1; // Add 1 to have 1 row of empty
                }
            }
            }

            var filepath = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\" + datetime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss") + ".xlsx");
            objExcelPackage.SaveAs(filepath);
        }
```

How to loop through each sub directories in a directory, then loop through all images from each sub directory using C#?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: hi @Micky, i get error on this line:'foreach (string img in subdir)', error is "cannot convert char to string".

Comment: This might give some idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29991439/cannot-convert-type-char-to-string

Comment: You may want to think about doing this kind of stuff in a separate service which your web app communicates with. Web Apps should have limited scope in underlying OS system.

Comment: @CallumLinington That depends.  Some people like _collapsed tiers_.

Comment: @Micky all I would be worried about is opening up vulnerabilities that allow attackers to access the OS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Janne Matikainen** answer is correct but you need to know how to modify in your code...

First change your code this line

```
 string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Folder"));
```

to

```
 string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetDirectories(Server.MapPath("~/Folder"));
```

Secondly you need to search file in your sub folder path which is your

```
foreach (string subdir in filesindirectory)
```

**subdir** is your path for your directory.

Just do back the same thing what you did to get the files

```
foreach (string img in  Directory.GetFiles(subdir))
```

After you finish the foreach subdirectory

```
foreach (string img in  Directory.GetFiles(subdir)) 
{
   // Your Code
}
// Reset the Count1
count1 = 0;
```

Reset it because you are increasing for dynamic row generating for each sheet.
Then you at new sheet and you didn't reset it. 
It will continue the count as per previous sheet.

To get the folder name you can easily get it by split. 
Before you create the worksheet you do as per below.

```
string[] splitter = subdir.Split('\\');
string folderName = splitter[splitter.Length - 1];
```

**Take NOTES** if the **folderName** contain some symbol it might not able to set it to excel worksheet and also the name cannot be too long. 
Please ensure that you replace with supportable symbol for excel worksheet

Comment: hi @Nic, thanks for your help! I have tried your solution but images appeared on 1 excel worksheet instead of all excel worksheets. Do you know how can I export Images from each subdirectory into each excel spreadsheet? For e.g. 10 subdirectories will have 10 excel worksheets in 1 excel workbook, thanks.

Comment: @FeliciaSoh After you finish the `foreach` for **subDirectories** please set back your `count1 = 0;`. Should fix it from what i see your image is imported to the worksheet but is on different rows..Updated Answer

Comment: hi @Nic, thanks for your help it works! btw do you mind explaining to me why do I need to reset the count1 to 0? Thanks!:)

Comment: hi @Nic, sorry I got 1 last question here, do you know how I can set each subdirectory name as each excel worksheet name?

Comment: hi @Nic, when I tried to add the images to the excel and after that I tried to delete the directory that have the images, it gives me the following error:"The process cannot access the file image1.png' because it is being used by another process." Do you know how can I close the image file that is being used in C# when I have exported the images to excel?

Comment: @FeliciaSoh Easy ways to delete it. Is end your Local IIS service or putting in `using` for the function which is `closeable` like `ExcelPackage` and etc

Answer (score 5):

This should list all files starting from C:\Images and go through all subdirs and their subdirs as well.

```
public void ExportToExcel()
{
    //for export
    var objExcelPackage = new ExcelPackage(); //create new workbook

    this.ListFiles(objExcelPackage, 0, Server.MapPath("~/Folder"));

    var filepath = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\" + datetime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss") + ".xlsx");
    objExcelPackage.SaveAs(filepath);
}

public void ListFiles(ExcelPackage objExcelPackage, int worksheetIndex, string path)
{
    var imageCount = 0;
    var x = 25;
    var finalValue = 0;

    var files = Directory.GetFiles(path).Select(s => new FileInfo(s));

    if (files.Any())
    {
        //create new worksheet
        var ws = objExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet" + (++worksheetIndex)); 

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            imageCount++;

            var TEST_IMAGE = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
            var myImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(img);
            var pic = ws.Drawings.AddPicture(imageCount.ToString(), myImage);

            // Row, RowoffsetPixel, Column, ColumnOffSetPixel
            if (imageCount > 1)
            {
                pic.SetPosition(finalValue, 0, 2, 0);
                finalValue += (x + 1); // Add 1 to have 1 row of empty row
            }
            else
            {
                pic.SetPosition(imageCount, 0, 2, 0);
                finalValue = (imageCount + x) + 1; // Add 1 to have 1 row of empty
            }
        }
    }

    foreach (var dir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
    {
        this.ListFiles(objExcelPackage, worksheetIndex, dir);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @Janne Matikainen, thanks for your solution, but is this for window application? Sorry if I am not clear in my post, I am working on a web application.

Comment: It's for console application but you can just copy the ListFiles() method for your web application. There is nothing specific about what kind of application it is, except the Console.WriteLine part :)

Comment: Edited my answer to exactly do what you would like to achieve.

Comment: @Janne Matikainen i think your first `worksheet` will be empty. Due to the image inside `subdirectory`

Comment: hi @Janne Matikainen, thanks for your help! I have solved this issue:)

Answer (score 2):

*Directory.GetFiles(dir)* returns all files in *dir*, without folders 
you should use *Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir)*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string dirPath = @"\\archives\2009\reports";

            List<string> dirs = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dirPath));

            foreach (var dir in dirs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", dir.Substring(dir.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0} directories found.",  dirs.Count);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UAEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(UAEx.Message);
        }
        catch (PathTooLongException PathEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(PathEx.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[The Composite Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) fits your problem here.

```
public interface IExcelWorksheetAdapter
{
    //todo: implement this method, here you have everything you need for an image file
    void AddPicture(FileSystemItem aFile);
}

public class FileSystemItem
{
    public virtual string FullPath { get; protected set; }
    public virtual int Level { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FullPath)) return string.Empty;
            return FullPath.Split('\\').Last();
        }
    }

    public virtual void Operation(IExcelWorksheetAdapter ws) { }
}

public class FolderItem : FileSystemItem
{
    public FolderItem(string fullPath)
    {
        Items = new List<FileSystemItem>();
        if (!Directory.Exists(fullPath)) return;

        FullPath = fullPath;

        var files = Directory.GetFiles(FullPath).Select(p => new FileItem(p) { Level = this.Level + 1 }).ToList();
        Items.AddRange(files);

        var subFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(fullPath).Select(p => new FolderItem(p) {Level = this.Level + 1}).ToList();
        Items.AddRange(subFolders);
    }

    public List<FileSystemItem> Items { get; set; }

    public override void Operation(IExcelWorksheetAdapter ws)
    {
        Items.ForEach(x => x.Operation(ws));
    }
}

public class FileItem : FileSystemItem
{
    public FileItem(string path)
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            FullPath = path;
        }
    }

    public override void Operation(IExcelWorksheetAdapter ws)
    {
        ws.AddPicture(this);
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class DirectoryCompositeTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Operation_for_a_directory_files()
    {
        var directory = new FolderItem(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
        directory.Operation(new Sample()); // give your IExcelWorksheetAdapter implementation here.

    }
}

public class Sample : IExcelWorksheetAdapter
{
    public void AddPicture(FileSystemItem aFile)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Indent(aFile.Level) + aFile.Name);
    }

    private string Indent(int level)
    {
        string result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
        {
            result += "-";
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```