# Streamreader read multiple log file folder in a loop vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

How to make the streamreader read multiple log file in folders in a loop. I have 100++ folder to go through. This code working fine but, I want to simplify the code using loop. This is my code so far:

```vb
Using a3 As New StreamReader("C:\read\mbi\3\MBI.log")
    Dim row3 As Integer

    Do Until a3.EndOfStream
        line = a3.ReadLine()
        Dim varray() As String = line.Split(CChar("-"))
        Dim dateTimeString As String = line.Substring(0, 21)
        Dim c As String = line.Substring(22)
        Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table1([Time] , [Process], [Oven], [line]) VALUES ( @line , @line1, '" & 3 & "', '" & row3 & "')", con1)
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@line", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dateTimeString
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@line1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = c
        con1.Open()
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con1.Close()
        row3 = row3 + 1
    Loop
End Using

Using a4 As New StreamReader("C:\read\mbi\4\MBI.log")
    Dim row4 As Integer

    Do Until a4.EndOfStream
        line = a4.ReadLine()
        Dim varray() As String = line.Split(CChar("-"))
        Dim dateTimeString As String = line.Substring(0, 21)
        Dim c As String = line.Substring(22)
        Dim cmd1, cmd2 As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table1([Time] , [Process], [Oven], [line]) VALUES ( @line , @line1, '" & 4 & "', '" & row4 & "')", con1)
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@line", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dateTimeString
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@line1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = c
        con1.Open()
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con1.Close()
        row4 = row4 + 1
    Loop
End Using
```

Comment: Here is the tip make paths dynamic using method to get directories then loop through those directories and read the files. Also if files reading is independent then you can also use multi threading to do simultaneous processing of log files and folders.

Comment: 1. How to loop through folders and files.[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33296943/643104)
2. How to iterate through directories and files using parallel class. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-iterate-file-directories-with-the-parallel-class). Do this things and if you face any issues then come here with them. I doubt anybody will give you ready code as you want in here.

Comment: Slightly off-topic but you should also give your `row3/row4` a default value, your using it before you've given it a value.