# Check and list sub-folders based on contents of folders C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a folder called `"C:\Foo\"` and in that folder, there are folders `"Bar"`, `"Bob"`, `"Bill"` and `"BAM"`. In each folder, there are a buncha files.

I wanna run through all of `"C:\Foo\"` subfolders and return folder names based on their contents or lack thereof:

```
foreach (folder in folders)
{
    if (folder !contains "someFile.pdf")
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(folder);
    }
```

So that `listBox1` will fill up with "Bob", "BAM" and "Bill" cuz they don't have someFile.pdf. So then I can see that Bob, BAM and Bill all don't have someFile.pdf in their folders.

I've checked around and I've found code that does similar stuff, but nothing to populate an list of subfolders based on their contents.

Comment: have you already checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33296318/loop-through-sub-directories-in-directory

Answer (score 6):

You will need to use `FileSystemObject` to iterate through your folders and files.

```
string[] files = 
    Directory.GetFiles("C:\Foo\","*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Refer to MDSN for details: [Directory.GetFiles Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx)

Or as @BradleyDotNet suggested (Thanks), use `EnumerateFiles`:

Refer to Docs for details: [Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles)

```
string sourceDirectory = @"C:\foo";

    try
    {
        var allFiles
          = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (string currentFile in allFiles)
        {
            string fileName = currentFile.Substring(sourceDirectory.Length + 1);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Or better, `EnumerateFiles` if there are a lot of them

Comment: @BradleyDotNET What's the difference?

Comment: @TnD_Guy `GetFiles` returns all files as an array, so it actually reads the entire directory in one shot. `EnumerateFiles` returns an IEnumerable and lazily reads the filesystem as it is consumed. In this case, it would allow for early termination of the read once a file was found.